# Add more columns to Excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using Excel and my .xlsx file has column XFD as the last column, but I have data requiring more columns.

Is it possible to add more columns?

Comment: for that many columns and (i'm assuming) also rows, why not consider using another data entry mechanism such as SQL or something? It looks like it would be harder in Excel for all the scrolling you have

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. I have never worked with SQL before. I can learn it, but before I try, do you have suggestions for other programs that maybe I do know? Thank you.

Comment: I can't think of others unfortunately, I haven't even used SQL myself but I know its used a lot with large data sets and thus there is a lot of support for learning it online. Perhaps Microsoft Access could help as its graphically based and may be easier to learn, though I have also not used it and it may turn out not be very helpful at all. Seeing as you already have Excel (thus MS Office) it may be worth looking into Access to see if it fulfils your requirement. Good luck

Comment: where is your data currently ?

Comment: **No**, it is not possible.

Comment: Thank you @QuickishFM.

Comment: @PeterH  My data are currently in a txt file, but that format does not work well for me, because it is hard to work with. For example, no sorting, etc, which is easy in Excel.

Comment: The only way to have more data, is by using a 2nd sheet. Excel is limited in how many columns you can have, and you seem to have reached the limit.

Comment: I was thinking I could maybe transpose/pivot the data, but I do not know if there are more rows than columns in Excel?

Comment: @SylviaRodriguez you can use powerquery to import the data, then transpose, there are 1048576 rows compared to 16384 columns. I don't have time to make an answer just google import data into power query, then google transpose in power query

Comment: Thank you. I will try.